# Pass a Java variable to a JavaScript method embedded in another Java method

Tags: java, javascript

I have the following Java code:

```
    public void nextElement()
    {
        try
        {
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
            System.out.println("Executing...");
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String input_tag = "input";
            js.executeScript(createHTML(input_tag));
            System.out.println("Completed execution..");
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I now need the `createHTML()` method to accept the value of the variable `input_tag` and pass the same to a JavaScript method embedded within the `createHTML()` Java method.

The `createHTML()` method looks a little like this:

```
    public String createHTML(String tag) //"tag" accepts value from "input_tag"
    {
        String temp = "";
        temp += "function test(javascript_tagname)"; //"javascript_tagname" should be the value passed in the Java variable "tag"
        temp += "{ ";
        temp += "  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('javascript_tagname');";
        temp += "  var i = 0;";
        temp += "  for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)";
        temp += "  {";
        temp += "     x[i].onclick = function()";
        temp += "     {";
        temp += "        var previousStyle = this.style.getAttribute('cssText');";
            -----------------
            -----------------
    }
```

So what do I need to specify that the argument `javascript_tagname` in the function `test()` is actually supposed to extract value from the passed Java argument "tag"?

I know it must be a wee-bit confusing. Kindly let me know for any clarifications.

Any help appreciated! :) :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but how about you move that javascript function into a `.js` file, load the js file into the `JavascriptExecutor`, and then do something like `js.executeScript(String.format("test(%s);", escape(input_tag)))` to invoke it?

Comment: Is your script just declaring the function, or is is actually invoking it?

Comment: @Chris Martin: I would not want to use an external .js file :)

Comment: @Maurice Perry: I don't invoke the function test() directly. I only call the function createHTML().

Comment: Why in the world not? You could load it from the classpath.

Comment: Well you must invoke it at some point

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind (hardcode) the value of a variable to script source the other 2 answers are the way to go. You will still have to call the function.

If you want to call the function and pass the argument don't hardcode the parameter in the script and just use invokeFunction method passing as arguments the name of the script function and list of arguments for the functions defined in script:

```
        engine.eval(createHTML());
        Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;
        invocableEngine.invokeFunction("test", "javascript_tagname" );
```

not sure what you want to do but a short working example:

```
public void nextElement()
{
    try
    {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
        System.out.println("Executing...");
        String input_tag = "input";
        engine.eval(createHTML(""));
        Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable) engine;
        invocableEngine.invokeFunction("test", "javascript_tagname_param" );
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String createHTML(String tag) //"tag" is not used
{
    String temp = "";
    temp += "function test(javascript_tagname)"; //"javascript_tagname" should be the value passed in the Java variable "tag"
    temp += "{ ";
    temp += "  println(javascript_tagname);";
    temp += "};";
    return temp;

}
```

output:

```
Executing...
javascript_tagname_param
```

Comment: Yes, sounds like the way to go

Comment: @user1121883: I may sound naive, but where do these lines go? In the method nextElement()?

Comment: Yes: they replace js.executeScript(createHTML(input_tag));

Comment: @user3571573 instead of  js.executeScript(createHTML(input_tag)); and input_tag is "javascript_tagname"

Comment: @user1121883 : Thanks for the explanation :)
But I would need a little more clarification. The blogs and tutorials that I came across mention that the parameter in the engine.eval() method is always a String type declared & assigned a value in the same class. But in my case, I would need the engine.eval() to call another Java method and then invoke the test() method with a parameter.
Any help with this? I'm kinda lost! :(

Comment: @user1121883: Thanks for the example. That really helped! :)
Now, is there something more to be mentioned to further use the variable 'javascript_tagname' in a statement like:
temp += "   var x = document.getElementsByTagName('javascript_tagname');"; 

Because I tried using the same line in my code and got an exception which read:
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1

Comment: @user1121883: Sorry if my original question did not communicate the exact problem. But that was precisely what I was looking for.

    public String createHTML(String tag) 
    {
        String temp = "";
        temp += "function test(javascript_tagname)"; //"javascript_tagname" should be the value passed in the Java variable "tag"
        temp += "{ ";
        temp += "  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('javascript_tagname');"; 
//I would want the variable 'javascript_tagname' in the above line to contain the same value as 'javascript_tagname' passed as parameter to function test()

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is more like this

```
public String createHTML(String tag) //"tag" accepts value from "input_tag"
{
    String temp = "";
    temp += "function test()";
    temp += "{ ";
    temp += "var javascript_tagname = \"" + jsonencode(tag) + "\";";
    temp += "  var x = document.getElementsByTagName(javascript_tagname);";
    temp += "  var i = 0;";
    temp += "  for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)";
    temp += "  {";
    temp += "     x[i].onclick = function()";
    temp += "     {";
    temp += "        var previousStyle = this.style.getAttribute('cssText');";
}
```

But the better solution is to see if there's a way to pass it in executeScript's varargs array, then pick it up in the script.

Answer (score 0):

As you create the JavaScript-code from scratch out of a String, why don't you simply replace it with the parameter?

```
String temp = "";
temp += "function test()";
temp += "{ ";
temp += "  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('" + tag + "');";
temp += "  var i = 0;";
temp += "  for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)";
temp += "  {";     
temp += "     x[i].onclick = function()";
temp += "     {";
temp += "        var previousStyle = this.style.getAttribute('cssText');";
```

Comment: In the line
temp += "  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('" + tag + "');";

I suppose the parameter still remains unknown to the function test, right?

Comment: The function won't neither have nor need any parameter afterwards, because you hard-code the value from Java into JavaScript.